# Adding Toggle Sidebar Menu In Blogger

Tags: jquery, blogger

I want to add a toggle left sidebar menu in blogger like this.

http://www.jqueryscript.net/menu/Mobile-App-Style-Toggle-Menu-Sidebar-Plugin-For-jQuery-Slidebars.html

I followed all the steps and tried many times but I couldn't manage to activate the plugin as you can see in following demo blog.
http://testing-prov4.blogspot.com
I have carefully added the CSS and Jquery coding but nothing seems to work.
What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your jquery reference.

[image]

Add below reference.

```
        <!-- jQuery -->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Slidebars -->
        <script src="slidebars/slidebars.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check with the below link.

http://jsfiddle.net/e6JnT/18/

```
$('.panel').hide();
```

$('button').click(function () {

```
$('.panel').animate({width:'toggle',left:'toggle'},800);
```

});